# Accessing result of map/reduce within Ionic2 app using PouchDB

Tags: ionic2, couchdb, pouchdb

I am using PouchDB on an Ionic 2 app that syncs with my CouchDB that is on AWS.

I have created a design document in futon and this works well if I go to http://my-ip-address:5984/wardround_jobs/_design/teams/_view/teams - I can see the JSON that is output by the map/reduce used in my design.

I am now trying to figure out how to access this in my app.

I start with this - it gives me all documents:

```
return new Promise(resolve => {

    this.db.allDocs({
    include_docs: true

    }).then((result) => {
        console.log(result);
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    }); 

});
```

I can then amend this to get back one specific document:

```
return new Promise(resolve => {

    this.db.get('0448071807c0f37f53e06aab54034a42').then((result) => {
        console.log(result);
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    }); 

});
```

But if I try and get back my design view using this code then I get back an error:

```
return new Promise(resolve => {

    this.db.get('_design/teams/_view/teams').then((result) => {
        console.log(result);
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    }); 

});
```

The error is:

```
CustomPouchError {
    status: 404, 
    name: "not_found",
    message: "missing", 
    error: true, 
    reason: "missing"
}
```

How can I access the result from my map/reduce within my app?

EDIT - with the help of Alexis I got this working ...

```
return new Promise(resolve => {

    this.db.get('teams/teams').then((result) => {
        console.log(result);
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    }); 

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the result from any map/reduce design document, you need to use the [**query()**](https://pouchdb.com/guides/queries.html) function.

Comment: Thanks Alexis.  I have tried with `this.db.query('_design/teams').then((result) => {` and `this.db.query('_design/teams/_view/teams').then((result) => {` and in both cases I get the same `CustomPouchError` error message

Comment: Ah ha, `this.db.query('teams/teams').then((result) => {` works!